# skip first column from data field and first column from data base table using format file

Tags: sql-server, dos, bcp

I have situation to loading quoted delimiter file into table using format file and bcp
file format:

```
"Col1"|"Col2"
"Col1"|"Col2"
```

Data base table columns `dLoadDate`, `col1`, `col2`

Can any one provide the format file for above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy, you can [create a format file using the bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx) (msdn.microsoft.com). The link has an easy example on how to do this. For specifying field delimeters, [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx) has an example using BULK INSERT on how to import the data with delimeters. HTH